# Mistake while adding double values in java

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
double d1=1000000000000000000.0; //which is equivalent to 1.0e^18
double d2=3434.0;
System.out.println(d1+d2);
```

which prints 1000000000000003460 instead of 1000000000000003434. What is the problem?

Comment: A double doesn't have the level of precision you need. Not enough significant digits.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - make that an answer, not a comment, because you are correct.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - and also provide an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Anthony Pegram is right. If you need such precision use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the double type itself, it doesn't support the precision you want. You should use BigDecimal.

Comment: Just curious, but why is he getting a BIGGER result than expected?  Does the lack of precision result in a rounding error?

Comment: Yes, lack of precision result. The double type is available to represent any 32-bit integer, but when it goes beyond this, the precision is less although you can represent some certain very big values.

Answer (score 0):

The number of storage required exceeds the expected. Use BIG Decimal in cases like these.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;//remember to import this
  public class UseBigDecimal{

   public static void main(String[]args){
   double d1=1000000000000000000.0;
   double d2=3434.0;

   BigDecimal bVal1 = new BigDecimal(d1);
   BigDecimal bVal2 = new BigDecimal(d2);

   BigDecimal sum = bVal1.add(bVal2);//you call the add() method not bVal1+bVal2
   System.out.println ("Sum of BigDecimals " +sum.toString());
   //need to call toString()
   }

  }
```